# Is there a way sort View by results of "Options" Rate/Voting API widget?

Tags: views, rating

I'm using the Rate module to allow voting on whether or not a given node is "Helpful" or "Unhelpful". I have a view with all nodes of this type, and the view includes a field for the Rate widget. I am having no problems displaying the widget itself, and the voting is working perfectly. However, I cannot for the life of me get any type of sorting functionality to work.

I've tried all of the sort types having to do with Vote, and all of them sort the nodes in no relevant order. It seems that the problem arises because I am using the value-type of "Options", and suggestions that I have found seem to require the value-type to be "Points". However, I'd much rather have user select between "Helpful" and "Unhelpful" than to use a thumbs up/down or +/- system of voting.

Does anybody know how I could sort by "most helpful" and "most unhelpful" and keep the value-type of "Options"?

Answer (score 5):

You have to add a relationship Content: Vote Results with proper data filters

- Value-type: Points
- Vote-tag: Your rate widget vote tag
- Aggregation-function: Number of vote

Then in views sort criteria add

- (Vote results) Vote results: Value (desc/asc)

Comment: So, is there no way to do this when the widget's value-type is set to options? I believe I need to have it set to this in order to give users the ability to select either "Helpful" or "Unhelpful", and provide a total number of votes for each. I realize that I could do a thumbs up/down system where opposite votes cancel eachother out, but I would like to show each value independently.